# Is it possible to hide my app from the recommendations in play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I've made a social networking app and I want the users to be the ones I want: I'm making an advertising campaign on specific places to get the specific users I want. The problem is that many users are coming from Google Play suggesting to download my app in the "related applications" section. The users that discover my app in that way are just spam accounts, they are not the target audience and they are generating spam by making accounts in my app. Is it possible to hide my app from all Google Play recommendations? I need to control my audience and this is a problem for me. It should be possible o search for my app by name or get it using a link to Google Play.

Comment: Have you considered running it as a beta rather than a released app?  I don't think there's a stronger georestriction than "country" right now.

Comment: Does beta disables recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

The option was available on old Google Play Console but ow it is not available.

what you can do now?

## **Option 1:**

[Make the app private](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#zippy=%2Callow-rd-party-developer-publishing%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization), from Google Play Console got to **Settings** > **Advanced settings** > **Managed Google Play** > and **Turn On** to Restrict access to your app.

[image: screen]

## **Option 2:**

Use deep link with your campaigns to know that this user is targeted, and show them normal app behavior.

if the user did not came from this deep link, make the sign up process very thorough (for example: ask them to provide a lot of details, email, secondary email, phone number, address) this will decrease spam drastically.